# Use mouseover to add animation on hover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an animation to an element when someone hover on it.

My thought is to add a class with keyframes and attach an mouseover event listener to it.

The reason I don't use CSS is because I want the animation to be finished even the mouse leave the element before the animation is finished. For example, the mouse is moved out of element when rotating on 180 degree (full animation is 360 degree)

But sadly it's not working and I don't know why...

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#rotate');

item.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e) {
  if(item) e.classList.add('rotate');
});
```

```css
#div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='rotate'></div>
```

Comment: I fixed the typo `,` error in your code

Comment: @James, thank you, I didn't realize it...Where is the typo?

Comment: it is between the `mouseover' function(e)`.  You could check in edit history. Also, the e in the function parmeter is incorrect use. Here the e is refers to event. You should use `this` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already on the right path. You can listen for the `animationend` event on the div and remove the `rotate` class when the event is fired. I've corrected your example snippet below.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#rotate');

item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if(item) item.classList.add('rotate');
});

item.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
  if(item) item.classList.remove('rotate');
});
```

```css
#rotate {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='rotate'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't change your code too much.

1. `e` refers to the event which is incorrect use of it, you should use this to target the current element
2. use `mouseenter` will be better in this sitution when you want to trigger an animation when use hover it .

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#rotate');

item.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(e) {
  if(item) this.classList.add('rotate');
});
```

```css
#rotate {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='rotate'></div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate James, but Loki solution is better because I indeed need the animation to be reused again.

Comment: @KarChung, don't be worry with that. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I would say you were pretty close. firstly you must change `#div` to `#rotate` then add the class directly to the item then when animation is done remove the class so that it can run again

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#rotate');

item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  item.classList.add('rotate');
});

item.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
  item.classList.remove('rotate');
});
```

```css
#rotate {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='rotate'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But Loki was the first one to give the correct answer...

Comment: Yeah was working on it at the same time, maybe an upvote